# how to bind scope/model with angular ui $modal.popup()

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a `ng-repeat` list view with each item has edit button. I want to open a modal popup and populate values associated with that list item into the popup fields.

I am loading the popup the usual way with `$scope.modalInstance = $modal.open({...});`

What I am struggling with is, how do I bind the scope of the popup! I know scope can be passed as a parameter while initializing it. But I want the popup to directly bind the fields with that specific list item.

I tried passing the list item like

```
var item = $scope.list[index];

$scope.modalInstance = $modal.open({
    ...,
    scope: item
});
```

But it gives error as `TypeError: $rootScope.$new is not a function`. May be this isn't the correct way I should bind the list item. Please guide in right direction.

Adding the full method which triggers editing of the list item

```
$scope.editItem = function (index) {
    $scope.item = $scope.api.select[index];

    $scope.modalInstance = $modal.open({
        templateUrl: 'templates/pupup-edit-item.html',
        scope: $scope,
    });

    $scope.modalInstance.result.then(function () {
        // ...
    }, function () {
        // $log.info('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());
    });
}
```

And the template,

```
<div class="modal-header">
        <h3 class="modal-title">Edit Item</h3>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
    <input ng-model="item.name" />
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="popup_Ok()">OK</button>
        <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="popup_Cancel()">Cancel</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you provide more of your codes?

Comment: Sure... Btw, it is the most basic form of popup which I want to bind to the `$scope.list[index]`. Basically a I want to edit a subset of the main model. Anyway, which specific code block you need to see?

Comment: I wanna see the whole function.

Comment: Here, I've added the whole function for you

Comment: By the way, can you provide also your html template?

Comment: Added it. Not sure how's that gonna help

Comment: Is this right `scope: $scope,` or is it `scope: $scope.item`?

Comment: Its `scope: $scope` and When I make `scope: $scope.item` it gives error as I mentioned in the question. But I got it working when I understood Simo Endre's answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you have a separate template with the modal window. Inside that template you define a local scope which is going to get populate by filtering the list of values from the controller.

So the modal content should look like this:

```
<div modal="isProductShowing" close="hideFullProduct()" options="productModalOptions">    
    <section class="container modal-body product-modal">    
        <button class="modal-body__close" ng-click="hideFullProduct()">Close</button>    

        <div class="product-modal__content">                
            <h1 class="product-modal__name">{{ currentFullProduct.name }}</h1>                            
        </div>                        
    </section>    
</div>
```

Then inside the controller you search for the product which is defined in the main template where you populate the list and associate the object to the scope of the modal window. So you need to filter the product which has the id defined as parameter in the listing template.

```
$scope.isProductShowing = false;

$scope.currentFullProduct = null;

$scope.productModalOptions = {
    backdropFade: true,
    dialogFade:true
};

$scope.showFullProduct = function (productId) {
    $scope.isProductShowing = true;
    $scope.currentFullProduct = _.findWhere($scope.products, { id: productId});
}
```

Only one thing remained: to trigger the modal window on click. This needs to be done on the main listing template:

```
<li ng-click="showFullProduct(product.productId)">
```

Hope it's clear, otherwise i can assist.

Answer (score 0):

yes you can bind like this, using `resolve`

```
    var modalInstance = $modal.open({

       ......
       .... 
        resolve: {
            item: function() {
                return $scope.item;
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: O! I failed to mention that my popup is using controller not a separate. Then I don't think I can use `resolve`. Also, the changes made in modal should directly reflect the original list from the model.

Comment: you can just use resolve parameter to pass the value